# Visual Studio 2019 Github extension commands: "pop and restore staged" vs "pop all as unstaged"?

Tags: git, visual-studio

What is the difference between the following commands in Visual Studio 2019 for GIT stash?

`pop and restore staged (--index)
pop All as unstaged`

while using https://visualstudio.github.com/

Answer (score 21):

Found a good article : https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019 - and here is the answer:

- **Pop/Apply and Restore Staged** – this will pop/apply the changes to
  your branch and it will also ensure that files that you had staged
  before are staged again
- **Pop/Apply All as Unstaged** – this will
  pop/apply the changes to your branch and it won’t stage the files
  that you had staged before.

If you hadn’t any staged files before you created the stash, then you won’t see a difference between the two options.